# Calabash takes ugly screenshot when borders are present in React Native app

Tags: react-native, calabash, calabash-ios

We use Calabash for functional testing and also screenshots taking for our react native app, but we ran into an issue with screenshots.

When one component has a border, the screenshot is messed up:

For example, with an `index.ios.js` such as:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => () => (
  <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <View style={{height: 100, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'red', borderColor: 'green', borderWidth: 10}}>
    </View>
  </View>
));
```

This is the display on simulator:

[image: On Simulator]

This is the screenshot taken (say by running `screenshot` after `calabash-ios console`):

[image: On screenshot]

Without the `borderWidth`, it works!

We're on RN 0.26.2, using calabash-cucumber 0.19.2.

Any help would be super appreciated!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by updating the `calabash-server` with a `calabash-ios download` :)